# replace nans with the first following non nan value (column - wise)

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, replace, nan

suppose I have the following matrix
a =

```
 2   NaN   NaN
 4   NaN     3
 3     7     9
 5    12     5
 8    10     8
12     5    10
```

I need to replace all nan values with the first following non-nan element(column wise). The desired new matrix should be:
b =

```
 2     7     3
 4     7     3
 3     7     9
 5    12     5
 8    10     8
12     5    10
```

Any ideas on how to do this in a general way?
Thank you in advance, Marios

Comment: What happens if the last element in a column is a NaN ?

Comment: that doesn't happen in my case, but I know this could be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the example data:

```
a = [
2 NaN NaN;
4 NaN 3;
3 7 9;
5 12 5;
8 10 8;
12 5 10;
];

% Here's the code:

b = a;

% Loop through all columns and all rows from bottom to top.
% If current element is not NaN and the element above is NaN,
% copy the value of current element to element above.
% If there are consecutive NaNs in the bottom of any column, they are not changed.

for colIndex = 1:size(b,2)
    for rowIndex = size(b,1):-1:2
        CurrentValue = b(rowIndex, colIndex);
        if ~isnan(CurrentValue) && isnan(b(rowIndex-1, colIndex))
            b(rowIndex-1, colIndex) = CurrentValue;
        end
    end
end
```